# How do I add new content to a plex library?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, plex

I am running plex on Linux Mint 18.02. I have created a new plex TV library.

@ /media/Plex/TV

It has scanned all the show in that folder, and display them all correctly.

Then I have gone and added a new folder to that library folder with a new show in it

@ /media/Plex/TV/NewShow

It does not recognise the new show. Does plex allow you to add new content to existing libraries? Do I have to remove the library and just ass it from scratch again everytime I add content?

Comment: On Windows I have to tell it to rescan the library or I have to wait for the scheduled task.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

1. The manual way. Hover your mouse over the library name and three dots will appear on the right of the name. Click the three dots and a menu will appear. In there will be a "rescan" option.
2. The automatic way. Go to the settings for Plex (usually above the libraries) and make sure that you are in the "server" settings (tabs will be on the right) then find the "Liraries" settings in the list on the left. In there should be several options to schedule updates on a regular basis or when media is added or changed. 
   [image]